# Can I generate xsd dynamically with Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, xsd, runtime

I want to get Variable names and their type in  from user, 
and to generate a xsd based on this information in run time.

I can't find any way to do this. Do you know some?

your help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [Castor](http://castor.org/xml-framework.html). You can generate a XSD from a XML. You need generate a XML before convert it to XSD whit this framework using the class [XMLInstance2Schema](http://www.castor.org/javadoc/org/exolab/castor/xml/schema/util/XMLInstance2Schema.html).

Comment: Thanks. and how can i generate that xml from the names and types I get from the user?